# Cleaning up Netsuite scripts

Tags: netsuite

Are there any suggestions for cleaning up unused scripts in NetSuite?  We have an implementation that includes scripts and bundles from a third party and then innumerable scripts (especially restlets and workflows) that we have written, changed, rewritten, tossed aside, etc by multiple developers.  Many of the scripts were released in error logging or don't have any debug log statements, which is the only way I can think to determine when, and how many times a script is run.

I am looking for a way to to determine just that - when and how often every script and/or deployment is run (hopefully without going into each script and adding log info), so we can clean up before the new version is implemented.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In version 14.2 (coming soon), there is a script queue monitor tool that should tell you when scripts are running, which queue is being used, etc (SuiteCloud Plus customers). See the release notes for 14.2 for more detail.

Comment: I found some preliminary info [here](http://www.netsuite.com/portal/landing/2013-2/platform.shtml).  It looks like what I need.

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can find is doing a Script Deployment search. You can condition on is Deployed = Yes/No, Status is anyof/noneOf Released/Scheduled, and Execution Log: Date within last year.

I am only giving example conditions based on what you mentioned. The Yes/No and anyof/Noneof depends on if you want to see those that are inactive (to clean them up) or those that are active. The execution log condition would only work if either the script errored (which does not require a nlapiLogExecution() call) or if there is a logExecution call in the script.

You could at least play with this a bit from what you know of your scripts to work off that. You can do a similar thing for Workflows by doing a workflow search.

Comment: I was going to try this method, but our upgrade is soon and the monitoring tools may do the job.  If they are not the greatest, this method with the fact the script and deployment records will now be exposed should help me clean up the mess.

Answer (score 0):

You could undeploy the scripts using a saved search. For example I want to undeploy the scripts which were created before a year ago.

```
   var start  = function(request, response)
{
    var filters = new Array();
    var columns = new Array();
    filters[0] = new nlobjSearchFilter('formuladate', null, 'before', 'lastfiscalyear');
    columns[0] = new nlobjSearchColumn('internalid');
    var search = nlapiSearchRecord('scriptdeployment', null, filters, columns);
    for(var i in search)
        {
            var rec = nlapiLoadRecord('scriptdeployment', search[i].getValue('internalid'));
            rec.setFieldValue('isdeployed', 'F');
            nlapiSubmitRecord(rec, true);
        }
}
```

Comment: What if I've a year past deployed script and still it is in use. You're assuming that all the past year deployed scripts are obsolete.

Comment: @Rockstar: you're right. We could add few filters for the last modified date  and check if it's active or not. Thank you for that help